# Adjust R Data Frame with Element Wise Function

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I am using RODBC to pull down server data into a data frame using this statement:

```
df <- data.frame(
                 sqlQuery(
                          channel      = ODBC_channel_string, 
                          query        = SQLquery_string
                          )
                 )
```

The resultant data set has the following grouping attributes of interest:

- Scenario
- Other Group By 1
- Other Group By 2
- ...
- Other Group By K

With key variables:

- [Time] = Future Year(i)
- [Spot] = Projected Effective Discount Rate For Year(i-1) to Year(i)

[Abbreviated Table Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4vav.png)

What I would like to do is transform the [Spot] column into a discount factor that is dependent on consistent preceding values:

- Scenario
- Other Group By 1
- Other Group By 2
- ...
- Other Group By K

With key variables:

- [Time] = Future Year(i)
- [Spot] = Projected Effective Discount Rate For Year(i-1) to Year(i)
- [Disc_0] = prod([Value]), for [All Grouping] = [This Grouping] and [Time] <= [This Time]

[Excel Version of Abbreviated Goal Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tsdX.png)

I could code the solution using a for loop, but I suspect that will be very inefficient in R if there are significant row counts in the original data frame.

What I am hoping is to use some creative implementation of dplyr's mutate:

```
df %>% mutate(Disc_0 = objective_function{?})
```

I think that R should be able to do this kind of data wrangle quickly, but I am not sure if that is the case. I am more familiar with SQL and may attempt to produce the necessary variable there.

Comment: Please [avoid screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451) and actually post data within body of text or post a `dput(head(mydata, 10))` dump. This sounds like an R only question and not involving database so sql-server (though is the source of your data) is not necessary to tag for question.